# ThinClient Pro HP

Tags: command-line, scripts, icons, display-resolution, .desktop

On our ThinClients we are running windows with two options:

1. launch a webbrowser and login to our Citrix session.
2. change the resolution to 1280x720.

I installed the ThinPro client on a test thinclient because we are trying to switch over to Linux as it is a lot faster. But the problem I am currently facing is I cannot create a script that changes the resolution.

Below is the script

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Version=1.0
GenericName= HP TC Connections Program
Name= (Company name)
Comment=firefox
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/www.svg
Exec=/usr/bin/connection-mgr start {e45233f9-ec1c-4e6c-9c01-bc1e8d82e4d}
Terminal=false
```

The code to change the resolution

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr -s 1280x720
```

My first thought was to add a path `Exec=(path to the script)` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to make it possible? I need 2 different icons:

- one to the normal citrix login and
- one icon with a code to change the desktop resolution, then launch the webbrowser to login to the Citrix session